# Можно ли зафиксировать нажатие на кнопку закрытия окна консоли Windows в python?

Tags: python, windows, консоль

Можно ли как-то поймать ивент, когда пользователь закрывает консольную программу.
И **перед закрытием** сделать какое-либо **действие**? Как это сделано в **PyGame Python**.

[image: Кнопка закрытия]

Comment: sys.exit(0) - тебе в помошь

Comment: если не понятно то я могу написать развернутый ответ, писать?

Comment: если помог пожалуйста не по скупись на "ответ полезен"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Судя по скриншоту у вас Windows.

Вам нужно установить обработчик закрытия консоли через функцию [SetConsoleCtrlHandler](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolectrlhandler) из Win32 API.

Вот пример:

```
import win32api
import os
import datetime                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

def on_exit(sig, func=None):
        with open("some.txt", mode='w') as f:
            f.write("Console closed: " + str(datetime.datetime.now()));
        print("exit handler")
        os.system('pause')

win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(on_exit, True)
while True:
    pass
```

Этот скрипт вызывает функцию `on_exit` при закрытии окна консоли и запускает программу `pause`, которая просит `Press any key to continue...`

На самом деле `on_exit` получает [несколько разных сигналов](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/handlerroutine), но в этом примере я не стал заморачиваться со специальной обработкой разных причин закрытия консоли.

Когда скрипт запускается из `cmd.exe`, оно действительно просит нажать любую кнопку.

Если же скрипт запускать из Windows Terminal, то терминал закрывается моментально, но тем не менее в `some.txt` записывается точный момент закрытия окна, то есть `on_exit` отрабатывает.

Answer (score 2):

Есть несколько вариантов решения твоей проблемы:

1. самый простой(наверное), без использования сторонних либ:

```
import sys
try:
    # сюда программу
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # если закрывается консоль то выполнять этот код
    sys.exit(0)
```

2. С использованием стороннего модуля `atexit`:

```
import atexit

def cleanup():
    # если программа завершается то выполнять этот код

atexit.register(cleanup)
```

функция `cleanup()` отслеживает выход из проги включая `Ctrl-C`

3. Используется модуль sigal, sys:

```
import signal
 import sys

 def signal_handler(signal, frame):
     #исполняемый код перед закрытием сюда
     sys.exit(0)

 signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
```

думаю здесь и так понятно.

Comment: Ничего не работает.. У меня к слову Windows 7 и python 3.8.8

Comment: В Windows не выполняется ни `cleanup` ни `signal_handler`

Comment: @PakUula можно ошибку?

Comment: @RNB можно ошибку

Comment: Нет ошибок. Для проверки я сделал функции `cleanup` и `signal_handler`, которые должны открыть файл и записать в него текущее время. Так вот, в Windows необходимые файлы не создаются. Что означает, что функции-обработчики не вызываются или не дорабатывают.